# sort a list of odd and even numbers

Tags: python, list, recursion

given a list of numbers i wish to sort the list such that odd numbers appear before even and i wish to do it recursively and in place since doing with loops is not that difficult.i get the error maximum recursion depth exceeded .here's my code:

```
def sep(l,i,j):
    def swap(l,i,j):
        (l[i],l[j]) = (l[j],l[i])
    n = len(l)
    i = 0
    j = n-1

    if l[i]%2 == 0:
        swap(l,i,j)
        j-=1
        return l 

   else:
        return  sep(l,i+1,j)
l =[5,13,12,4,6,9]
i =0
j =len(l)-1
print(sep(l,i,j))
```

Comment: Do the odd and even numbers need to be sorted within themselves? What is your expected output with your `l` above?

Comment: the output should be:[5,13,9,12,4,6]

Comment: You are setting i and j inside the sep function. Once it has passed the first swap condition, it will go through infinite recursion.

Comment: Also return l will never be hit, as you either call swap again or you call  it in the else. You need some kind of test to return before your recursive calls.

Comment: but to invok recursion i have to set i and j inside sep function.anyway else i can invoke recursion. also i put the test if i >j it would return l but that didn't work also.

Comment: There is no need to set i and j to (practically speaking) constant values at the beginning of the function. This effectively remove the purpose of recursion as it simply examines the same pair of data points on each iteration.

The if i >= j should be present somewhere in your code. I'm guessing your problems were with another section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# called with list, 0, len(list)-1
def sep(lst, first, last):
    def swap(l, x, y):
        l[x], l[y] = l[y], l[x]
    # basecase: done searching list
    if first == last or first > last:
        return lst
    # even left: continue ignoring the first
    if lst[first] % 2 == 0:
        return sep(lst, first+1, last)
    # odd left: continue ignoring the last
    if lst[last] % 2 == 1:
        return sep(lst, first, last-1)
    swap(lst, first, last)
    return sep(lst, first+1, last-1)
l = [5,13,12,4,6,9]
print sep(l, 0, len(l)-1)
```

Yah, and the problem with yours is in the comment. If you keep setting i and j inside the function, any list that requires a recursive call to sep will keep on repeating, setting i to 0 and j to the length of the whole list minus 1

To invoke recursion you do not need to set i and j, you need to increment and decrement them each time. They are how you know your recursion is done. Once you have moved through the list to the point where each pointer in your list is pointing at each other, or have already passed each other, then you are done.

You don't want to return 1 when you are done, you want to return the list. You also want to make sure to decrement j after swapping it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def rec(lst, start, end):
    if start == end:
        return lst
    elif lst[start] % 2 == 0 and lst[end] % 2 == 1:
        lst[start], lst[end] = lst[end], lst[start]
        return rec(lst, start+1, end-1)
    elif lst[start] % 2 == 0:
        return rec(lst, start, end-1)
    else:
        return rec(lst, start+1, end)



def rec_sort(lst):
    return rec(lst, 0, len(lst)-1)


print rec_sort([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works in the expected manner. As for why *your* code doesn't work, I think @AMacK's and @JohnBarca's comments should be helpful:

```
lst = [5,13,12,4,6,9]

def sep(l,i):
    if len(l)-i < 2: return
    for j in range(len(l)-i):
        if l[i]%2==0 and l[i+j]%2==1:
            l[i],l[i+j] = l[i+j],l[i]
    sep(l,i+1)

sep(lst,0)

>>> print lst
[5, 13, 9, 4, 6, 12]
```

Comment: I think he didn't want to use loops

Answer (score 0):

If its not the case to use own function or recursion, `sorted()` suitable for this

```
arr = [5,13,12,4,6,9]
arr = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (x % 2 == 0, x))
print(output)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[5, 9, 13, 4, 6, 12]
```